# Flutter web error messages are non-clickable

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

I am getting error messages in both Android Studio and VS Code that are non-clickable when deploying to Web. In the screenshot below I have set up Android Studio and VS Code side by side. In Android Studio you can see the the HTTP links from the JS code are working but not the more useful Dart code links. In particular the highlighted line `packages/afi_desktop_app/ui/screen/ecg_chart/ecg_chart_repo.dart 24:5`  would be useful as that is code that I wrote.

[image: Screenshot of VS Code and Android Studio with error messages lacking links]

Note that this is code that I had initially created for Desktop use. I have now upgraded and changed the code base to work with web. It's also worth mentioning that I seem to get the same issue when starting a new Counter App Flutter example application from scratch.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.4, on macOS 11.2.1 20D74 darwin-arm, locale
    en-NL)
    • Flutter version 2.0.4 at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/1.22.5/flutter
    • Framework revision b1395592de (13 days ago), 2021-04-01 14:25:01 -0700
    • Engine revision 2dce47073a
    • Dart version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/gerard/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.21.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 11.2.1 20D74 darwin-arm
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.128
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: I have not, unfortunately

Comment: . That's strange, as far as I can see, people on youtube developing with Flutter web have clickable stack traces.

Comment: Can you share a link to one of those videos so I can add it to the questions?